# The 'gems' configuration option edit name

Tags: ruby, web, jekyll

When I use the latest jekyll and start its server, a certain warning below shows up:

Configuration file: C:/Users/recup/Grape-Theme/_config.yml
       Deprecation: The 'gems' configuration option has been renamed to 'plugins'. Please update your config file accordingly.

I followed the following steps to solve the problem:
1. Open your _config.yml file
2. Find the line beginning with gems:
3. Replace gems with plugins

But, the problem continue. What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to reproduce this locally.
Here are some options:

- Verify you saved the `_config.yml` after you corrected it. (it happens!)
- Run the command `bundle exec jekyll doctor -t`. The command `jekyll doctor` is used to search the site for deprecation warning. The flag `-t` will show a backtrace if an error occurs.